# Reapeating android permissions pop ups

Tags: android, google-maps, permissions

I'm a very new android programmer and im currently playing around with google maps. At the moment i am trying to find my current location on the map. I struggled to understand and implement the permissions pop up that's needed but now i have to problem that the pop up will constantly pop up. So it pops up I allow it access then it disappears only to repeat the process again and again until I deny it access. Sorry if this is a easy question but i am really struggling.

Here's the code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng Uni = new LatLng(53.767735, -0.368377);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Uni).title("Hull University"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Uni));

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }




    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
            int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,
                            "Permission was granted",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this,
                            "Permission denied",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps

try this :

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng Uni = new LatLng(53.767735, -0.368377);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Uni).title("Hull University"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Uni));

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);



    }else if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }







}
```

Make Sure you have include Required permissions in manifest file too

```
<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: can u please then mark the answer as accepted, for other to get benefit from this solution @madaxehamster01